# Pagination of an existing html table, shown in an IFrame on an MVC 4 razor view

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, iframe, razor

First off, I am using an MVC 4 web application using the razor view engine, and the File Path comes from a Windows Communication Foundation application.

I am attempting to show an HTML file inside of an IFrame with pagination. The table is produced from a database, and is fed into an XSL stylesheet from an XML document in code. The filepath is returned as a string, and is loaded into the IFrame perfectly fine. I am able to view the table and scroll as necessary.

The problem comes in where I need to split the already existing HTML table into different pages because the table can be too large, thousands of lines of data.

Here is a sample, shortened version of an input html. This file will come in as a string.

string filePath = @"C:\documents\visualstudio2010\projects\myproject\Temp\Pagination.html";

```
<!DOCTYPE html />
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.Pagination.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<title></title>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <th>
                Names
            </th>
            <th>
                Age
            </th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    John Smith
                </td>
                <td>
                    30
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Jane Smith
                </td>
                <td>
                    29
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
  <body>
</html>
```

Here is my view to produce the IFrame.

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.Pagination.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/sorttable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/dragtable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.pagination.css" rel="stylesheet"
     type="text/css" />
@{
     ViewBag.Title = "HtmlDisplay";
}
<html>
<head>
    <title>Save as example</title>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
        var now = false;
        function saveIt() {
            if (now) { document.execCommand("SaveAs"); }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="now=true">
    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="saveIt();">
        <img style="height: 40px; width: 40px; display: inline;"             src="../../Content/images/go_down_blue.png"
        alt="" />
</a>
</body>
</html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Print Iframe From Parent</title>
    <style>
        body
        {
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 12px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var header_friendly = '<div style="position: relative; text-align: center; border-bottom: 2px     solid black; font-family: verdana; font-size: 11px; padding: 5px; padding-top: 1px; color: darkred">This is a printer friendly version of the page. Click <button style="cursor: pointer" onclick="window.print(); parent.document.getElementById(\'ifr_friendly\').style.left=\'-10000px\'">PRINT</button> to print it. Click <button style="cursor: pointer" onclick="parent.document.getElementById(\'ifr_friendly\').style.left=\'-10000px\'">CLOSE</button>  to close this window without printing.<\/div>'

    function printer_friendly(which, left, top, width, height) {
        frames['ifr_friendly'].document.body.innerHTML = header_friendly +     frames[which].document.body.innerHTML;
        document.getElementById('ifr_friendly').style.left = left;
        document.getElementById('ifr_friendly').style.top = top;
        document.getElementById('ifr_friendly').style.width = width;
        document.getElementById('ifr_friendly').style.height = height;
    }};
</script>
<div>
    <!-- Order: name of the printer-friendly-iframe, left, top, width, height  -->
    <a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="printer_friendly('ifr', '5%', '5%', '90%', '90%')">
        <img src="../../Content/images/print-256.png" alt="" style="height: 40px; width: auto;" />        </a>
    <iframe class="sorttable dragtable" id="ifr" name="ifr" style="position: absolute; left: 15%;     top: 45%; width: 70%;
        height: 60%;" src="..\..\Temp\Pagination.html"></iframe>
    <!-- The printer friendly window -->
    <iframe id="ifr_friendly" name="ifr_friendly" style="position: relative; z-index: 10000;
        background: white; left: -10000px; border: 1px solid black"></iframe>
</div>
```

I have attempted to use JQuery to page the table, but it did not go as planned. If I do end up using some type of JQuery, it has to be 1.8 or lower to be used in IE8. You may be asking why don't I just make different tables, and have an on-click to produce the next html page. That is possible, but I cannot do that due to my requirements.

Any input is welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have two simple options, the javascript datatable library and the ASP.NET MVC article on pagination: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using an MVC WebGrid instead? They have paging built in and will generate the actual HTML for you. I'm assuming you have the option of grabbing your data directly from the database instead of grabbing pre-rendered HTML.

MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288075.aspx

Code would look something like...

```
@{
     var grid = new WebGrid(model)
}
@if (grid.TotalRowCount > 0)
@grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "WebGridTableStyle", alternatingRowStyle: "WebGridAlternatingRowStyle", rowStyle: "WebGridRowStyle", headerStyle: "GridHeader", columns: grid.Columns(
    grid.Column("Name", format: @<text>@item.Name</text>),
    grid.Column("Age", format: @<text>@item.Age</text>)))
@grid.Pager(
    mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
    numericLinksCount: 5,
    firstText: "<<",
    previoustext: "<",
    nextText: ">",
    lastText: ">>")
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, Data cannot be sent directly to the UI in the form of DataTables/DataSets. The separation allows for a style sheet to be changed out with a simple drag and drop on the server, and an updated service reference.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using JavaScript to hide the tables. In the Style Sheet I created a different table ID for each table that was created (the tables were created using recursion). In the head tag created by the style sheet I added a javascript function to hide the table. It used document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';. Of course, this is not true pagination, but it did render the effects that I was going for, without having to create multiple html files. The hrefs were created using recursion as well so that the number of pages matched the number of tables. Previous and next buttons went through a for loop which checked the display of the tables and if the table display was  equal to 'block' it rendered that table as 'none' and rendered the one previous or next to that table as block. Obviously with index checking to make sure it didn't go past the number of tables produced.